# Jetpack Compose Draw Line Chart with Circle Dot on each point

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I've looking to draw an line chart on a canvas in Jetpack Compose with a little circle on the every point

[image]

Line chart draw perfectly the main problem occur when I am draw circle dot on each point. Basically I am using quadraticBezierTo() function for perfect curve the code I try is below:

```
Canvas(modifier = modifier) {
    val spacePerHour = (size.width - spacing) / points.size
    var lastX = 0f
    val normX = mutableListOf<Float>()
    val normY = mutableListOf<Float>()

    val strokePath = Path().apply {
        val height = size.height
        for (i in points.indices) {
            val point = points[i]
            val nextInfo = points.getOrNull(i + 1) ?: points.last()
            val leftRatio = (height / 100) * point
            val rightRatio = (height / 100) * nextInfo

            val x1 = spacing + i * spacePerHour
            val y1 = height - spacing - leftRatio.toFloat()
            val x2 = spacing + (i + 1) * spacePerHour
            val y2 = height - spacing - rightRatio.toFloat()
            
            // Circle dot points
            normX.add(x1)
            normY.add(y1)

            if (i == 0) {
                moveTo(x1, y1)
            }

            lastX = (x1 + x2) / 2f

            quadraticBezierTo(
                x1, y1, lastX, (y1 + y2) / 2f
            )
        }
    }
    val fillPath = android.graphics.Path(strokePath.asAndroidPath())
        .asComposePath()
        .apply {
            lineTo(lastX, size.height - spacing)
            lineTo(spacing, size.height - spacing)
            close()
        }
       drawPath(
        path = fillPath,
        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
            colors = listOf(
                transparentGraphColor,
                Color.Transparent
            ),
            endY = size.height - spacing
        )
    )

    drawPath(
        path = strokePath,
        color = graphColor,
        style = Stroke(
            width = 3.dp.toPx(),
            cap = StrokeCap.Round
        )
    )

    (normX.indices).forEach {
        drawCircle(
            Color.White,
            radius = 3.dp.toPx(),
            center = Offset(normX[it], normY[it])
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I issue is that dot circle is not on the line

Comment: Check this open-source library https://github.com/MahmoudIbrahim3/android-compose-charts

Comment: The curve isn't perfect, it's not reaching the actual points. What you should be looking at is getting the curve to the right points.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use Cubic Bézier, here you can find a good article:

https://medium.com/@pranjalg2308/understanding-bezier-curve-in-android-and-moddinggraphview-library-a9b1f0f95cd0

To keep the example simple I assumed that the value points on the y-axis were already computed:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.*
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun CubicChart(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    yPoints: List<Float> = listOf(
        199f, 52f, 193f, 290f, 150f, 445f
    ),
    graphColor: Color = Color.Green
) {

    val spacing = 100f
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(all = 16.dp)
    ){

        Canvas(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
        ) {
            drawRect(
                color = Color.Black,
                topLeft = Offset.Zero,
                size = Size(
                    width = size.width,
                    height = size.height
                ),
                style = Stroke()
            )

            val spacePerHour = (size.width - spacing) / yPoints.size

            val normX = mutableListOf<Float>()
            val normY = mutableListOf<Float>()

            val strokePath = Path().apply {

                for (i in yPoints.indices) {

                    val currentX = spacing + i * spacePerHour

                    if (i == 0) {

                        moveTo(currentX, yPoints[i])
                    } else {

                        val previousX = spacing + (i - 1) * spacePerHour

                        val conX1 = (previousX + currentX) / 2f
                        val conX2 = (previousX + currentX) / 2f

                        val conY1 = yPoints[i - 1]
                        val conY2 = yPoints[i]


                        cubicTo(
                            x1 = conX1,
                            y1 = conY1,
                            x2 = conX2,
                            y2 = conY2,
                            x3 = currentX,
                            y3 = yPoints[i]
                        )
                    }

                    // Circle dot points
                    normX.add(currentX)
                    normY.add(yPoints[i])

                }
            }


            drawPath(
                path = strokePath,
                color = graphColor,
                style = Stroke(
                    width = 3.dp.toPx(),
                    cap = StrokeCap.Round
                )
            )

            (normX.indices).forEach {
                drawCircle(
                    Color.Black,
                    radius = 3.dp.toPx(),
                    center = Offset(normX[it], normY[it])
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Line Chart with cubic bezier]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32328394)